# Scala can not resolve append

Tags: scala

I want to remove all instances of an element from a list, like this:

```
  def remove(x: Char, xs: List[Char]) = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x :: ys => remove(x, ys)
    case y :: ys => y :: remove(x, ys)
  }
```

However, I get an error on the line `case y :: ys => y :: remove(x, ys)` saying `Cannot resolve symbol ::`

Am I pattern matching correctly?

Comment: Is there some reason for not using filter? ie. xs.filter(_ != x)

Comment: It's "prepend", not "append", too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a couple of different compile errors, first: "error: recursive method remove needs result type" (fixed by adding return type of `List[Char]`), then (as I expected): "warning: unreachable code" on the line with `y :: ys`. This latter warning comes because the `x` used in the line with `case x :: ys` is not recognised as the same `x` from the function's arguments - it is shadowing the argument variable, and so matched *any* character.

To be sure to match the function argument, add backticks:

```
def remove(x: Char, xs: List[Char]): List[Char] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case `x` :: ys => remove(x, ys)
  case y :: ys => y :: remove(x, ys)
}
```

or you can capitalise the argument name (capitalised variables in a match case are treated specially this way):

```
def remove(X: Char, xs: List[Char]): List[Char] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case X :: ys => remove(X, ys)
  case y :: ys => y :: remove(X, ys)
}
```

If using this style, don't forget to capitalise the argument everywhere it is referenced!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the return type if you are using recursive call. This will work:

```
 def remove(x: Char, xs: List[Char]):List[Char] = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x :: ys => remove(x, ys)
    case y :: ys => y :: remove(x, ys)
}
```

I agree, the error is misleading

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that a recursive method needs to declare its return type.

```
def remove(x: Char, xs: List[Char]): List[Char] = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x :: ys => remove(x, ys)
    case y :: ys => y :: remove(x, ys)
}
```

The second problem is that both `case`s are the same so the second one is unreachable.

Comment: That's right, I didn't notice the similar cases. It compiles though with a warning